# Delete a list from a list based on .count Python

Tags: python, list, count

I have the following lists inside a list

```
results=[['hgd', '2.96', '4,433,389', '-13.7'], ['bbd.a', '2.25', '1,209,421', '-13.1'], ['mri.u', '8.60', '3,000', '-8.5'], ['iam', '1.06', '1,000', '-7.8'], ['hnd', '21.76', '1,180,466', '-7.6'], ['tth', '0.97', '41,777', '-7.6'], ['bbd.b', '1.89', '32,423,597', '-7.4'], ['bbd.pr.c', '15.20', '43,737', '-7.3'], ['esp', '1.96', '87,604', '-7.1'], ['enl', '34.00', '5,239', '-6.2'], ['rmp', '1.83', '2,688,261', '-5.7'], ['amm', '1.39', '63,301', '-5.4'], ['vrx', '41.83', '1,664,689', '-5.4'], ['xtc', '13.45', '63,453', '-5.3'], ['cxr', '36.48', '1,642,197', '-5.0']]
```

This list updates daily. Sometimes there is a list where the 1st element has two periods (.)  like the following bbd.pr.c

```
['bbd.pr.c', '15.20', '43,737', '-7.3']
```

When this happens I want the entire list deleted. Not to sure to how to go about doing this. Using the count function.

```
.count('.')<=1
```

Any help?

Comment: @dbliss: It is a [Common Sequence Operation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations)

Comment: @zondo ok. it's a method that is here being called without an associated object.

Answer (score 1):

For python 2, use [**filter**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
results=[['hgd', '2.96', '4,433,389', '-13.7'], ['bbd.a', '2.25', '1,209,421', '-13.1'], ['mri.u', '8.60', '3,000', '-8.5'], ['iam', '1.06', '1,000', '-7.8'], ['hnd', '21.76', '1,180,466', '-7.6'], ['tth', '0.97', '41,777', '-7.6'], ['bbd.b', '1.89', '32,423,597', '-7.4'], ['bbd.pr.c', '15.20', '43,737', '-7.3'], ['esp', '1.96', '87,604', '-7.1'], ['enl', '34.00', '5,239', '-6.2'], ['rmp', '1.83', '2,688,261', '-5.7'], ['amm', '1.39', '63,301', '-5.4'], ['vrx', '41.83', '1,664,689', '-5.4'], ['xtc', '13.45', '63,453', '-5.3'], ['cxr', '36.48', '1,642,197', '-5.0']]

results = filter(lambda l: l[0].count('.') <= 1, results)
```

For python 3:

```
results = list(filter(lambda l: l[0].count('.') <= 1, results))
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never thought `filter` is particularly readable in comparison to list comprehensions, especially if you have to use a lambda. Here's the equivalent of Smac89's answer, for both Python versions:

```
results = [x for x in results if x[0].count('.') <= 1]
```

(`x` corresponds to `l` but `l` is not generally a good name because `1`, `l`, and `I` all look too similar)